# Parsing a csv using a reverse escape char

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to parse a large csv file (e.g. converting it to pandas df). It is an unquoted CSV, with a comma as the delimiter. I received the file as txt, and changed the extension to csv. I now see that some of the fields represent free text, and have commas as part of it. I was thinking of using a heauristic where a delimiter-comma will never have space following it, while a free-text comma will, in most cases, be followed by a space.

The problem is that using `escapechar = ' '` marks the chars followed by the escape, while I need it to escape the preceding character.

Is there a way to mark a reverse-escape char?

I was considering the alternative of replacing all ", " with "#$#$#$#", but the file is 3 gb and it feels super inefficient.

Another option is to send the file back, complaining that it's malformed. Problem is that it will hurt my pride.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don''t you replace ', ' (comma + space) chars with ';' (semicolon) so that you can import your csv as it's delimiter semicolon?

Comment: There is no need to replace everything in the file; just loop over each line, replace what needs to be replaced, then import from the modified string.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a wrapper to massage each line given to the csv reader:

```
# foo.csv:
col1,col2,col3, with, commas,col4

# python file:
def escape_commas(filelike):
    for line in filelike:
        yield line.replace(', ', '\\, ')

with open('foo.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(escape_commas(csvfile), escapechar='\\')
    for row in reader:
        print('|'.join(row))

# result:
col1|col2|col3, with, commas|col4
```

Edit: for pandas you might want to make a wrapper for file that implements the read method:

```
class EscapeCommas():
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
    def read(self, size=-1, /):
        text = self.file.read(size)
        return text.replace(', ', '\\, ')

with open('foo.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    pd.read_csv(EscapeCommas(csvfile), escapechar='\\')
```